# print php for each values in variable

Tags: php

I am very new to php.I have a foreach loop

```
foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {

echo 'index is '.$w.' and value is '.$h;}
```

I need to assigning these values (I have 2 values) in to variables

```
$firstItem = foreach value 1

$secondItem = foreach value 2
```

How can I do this
Thanks

Comment: use `list($firstItem, $secondItem) = $sizes`

Comment: What values do you want to assign?  Can you show `$sizes` structure?

Answer (score 2):

Use list() function as

```
list($firstItem, $secondItem) = $sizes;
echo $firstItem , ' ', $secondItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this.

```
list($firstVariable,secondVariable) = $sizes;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {

$firstItem = $sizes[$w1];
$secondItem = $sizes[$w2];
}
```

where $w1 is first key AND $w2 is second key

Comment: Here is the full function.This is an image re size function.once image uploaded this will generate 2 images.But I need to assing these 2 images in separate variables

if( $_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_file_size ){
  // get file extension
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
   /* resize image */
   foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {
    
    echo $files[i] = resize($w, $h0);

   }

   

  } else {
   $msg = 'Unsupported file';
  }

Answer (score 0):

According to comment of Tamil Selvan

```
<?php
$sizes = array("5","10");
list($firstItem, $secondItem) = $sizes;
echo $firstItem." - ".$secondItem;
?>
```

The result like

```
5 - 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
//what is in "sizes"?
$sizes=array('a'=>'foo',
             'b'=>'bar');    

foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {
${"item".$w}=$h;
}

echo "item a is ".$itema //item a is foo
echo "item b is ".$itemb //item b is bar
```